# React native FlatList horizontal Left to right pull refresh

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have got multiple FlatLists with Horizontal set to true. I want to implement functionality so that when user reaches on the first item (left hand side) and tries to pull left it refreshes the content. I can not use RefreshControl as it works when pulled down. Has anyone implemented Left to right swipe refresh on the first item? Any hints will be much appreciated.

I am thinking of an alternative: putting a button in header and ActivityIndicator.  When user will click on that button it will trigger the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Its too late but today I faced same issue and no one has yet implemented such component.

But I found an easy and a bit inefficient way to refresh multiple horizontal lists inside scrollview and it is by adding a RefreshControl to the Scrollview itself and refresh all the lists at once with it.

you can check out how the refresh control works [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/refreshcontrol)